# What can you use Maaser for?

Tags: money, maaser-tithes

What can maaaser money be used for? Can you use maaser to buy sefarim?
Thanks

Comment: see point 3 from https://halachablog.com/2016/08/18/the-laws-of-maaser-money/ - http://dinonline.org/2014/01/25/maaser-money-for-sefarim/ - https://doseofhalacha.blogspot.com/2014/03/buying-seforim-with-maaser.html